# autosar-RTE module responsible-to-handle the timing of Message to RTE

Tags: autosar, runtime-environment

Can someone explain which module is responsible to handle the timing of Message to RTE?

I am really new to autosar, and I am really confused about this point

Comment: This question does not make any sense at all. Rephrase it and state your actual problem in more detail.

Comment: My doubt is which module is responsile to handle the messages which are being sent and recieved by RTE

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to transmit and receive IPDUs e.g. over CAN, there are the Com and the LdCom modules, which will handle them. Com will also handle Periodic, Triggered or Mixed handling of transmission. The Com has knowledge about ISignalGroups and ISignals mapped to ISignalIPdus, and which ISignals are triggering SendEvents. The same is for reception, and the mapping to SWC ports and triggering of e.g. DataReceivedEvent, DataReceiveErrorEvent ...

The information is derived from the SystemDescription used in the configuration.

Maybe you should take a closer look into the  [AUTOSAR_EXP_LayeredSoftwareArchitecture.pdf](https://www.autosar.org/fileadmin/user_upload/standards/classic/21-11/AUTOSAR_EXP_LayeredSoftwareArchitecture.pdf)  file.